# Pivot data into field and values

Tags: sql

I am having a table consisting of multiples rows and columns. I need to pivot down this table into 2 column consisting of field and values.

for Example my Input table is:

```
Name Class Subject
Sam   2     Math
John  3    Science
Amy   4     Music
```

output Required:

```
Field  Values
Name   Sam
       John
       Amy
Class   2
        3
        4
Subject Math
        Science
        Music
```

I tried everything but nothing works for me. I am looking for solution in excel, Tableau or SQL. Anything works for me. It would be great if you help me with the logic. Thank you in advance

Comment: you need to decide what tool you want to focus on.

Comment: I have a dataset of 100k records. I am mainly looking solution in SQL query

Answer (score 0):

In SQL this is done with `UNION`

```
SELECT 'Name' AS Field, Name AS Values ORDER BY Class
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Class' AS Field, Class AS Values ORDER BY Class
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Subject' AS Field, Subject AS Values ORDER BY Class
```

If there are more columns, just continue the pattern.

`ORDER BY Class` assumes that `Class` is a unique key of the table, to ensure that each subquery is ordered consistently. If this isn't true, replace that with the actual primary key.